# Altering the CSS added by an Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

How do we override the CSS created by an angular directive.  For example when we add the add the sort directive to the material data table it [creates this problem (It overrides the layout of the column header).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750213/centering-text-vertically-in-a-mat-header-col).

Overriding the CSS via `styles.scss` or the components local CSS, does not work, because the directive adds an inline style which has priority.  Also tried adding `!important` to the CSS definition override, but no love.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest one method, write a custom CSS class in your component's CSS/SCSS file and apply it using a condition with NgClass directive,
execute your condition within onInit.

just try and see, I hope it'll work

Comment: Better to execute on `ngAfterViewInit` if you want to do that but `ngclass` and adding a class are the same thing

Comment: yes better use ngAfterViewInit, but adding a class or ngClass is not same in this moment. both will add a class but we should carefully when to add the class.  if add a class directly, it will override by directive's styles, that why we need to add out class after all other styles are applied

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) or [Angular Style Binding](https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/) if classes' style is not being applied. Best way is to use `ngdeep`

If this still doesn't work put it on a `setTimeout` or `ngAfterViewChecked` (Not recommended tho.).

Comment: IIUC ngdeep is depcreated.

Comment: Yup says it's deprecated.

Comment: Until then `::ng-deep` should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.